# Caching in Ember with DS.ActiveModelAdapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

My Ember app pulls data from a Rails backend by way of active_model_serializers on the back end and DS.ActiveModelAdapter on the front. Everything is working well, but I don't understand the caching strategy.

According to the Emberjs.org docs caching is automatic:

> The store will automatically cache records for you. If a record had
>   already been loaded, asking for it a second time will always return
>   the same object instance.

However, whenever I visit the following route (app/routes/suppliers.js), the adapter pulls the data anew from the server:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('Supplier');
  }

});
```

I notice that when I visit a detail route (at app/routes/supplier.js), the server is not called, as the single record is presumably re-used from the collection.

Since my app is basically read-only, and won't need a lot of updates, I want to cache that entire collection (until I choose to invalidate the cache) so that I can pop back and forth between detail views and collection views without the lag of refreshing the collection data from the server.

Comment: The purported duplicate answer is over a year old (eons in Ember time), and doesn't address my basic question: why do the Ember docs say caching is automatic when it apparently isn't?